# Will access to university dropbox instantly disappear once I lose affiliation?

Tags: dropbox

I have a dropbox that is provided by my university. I log in using the certificate (I believe it is called a "single sign-on" or something) that I use to sign on to all other school-related things at my university, not a username and password, and there's some ridiculous amount of shared space; thousands of terabytes or something like that.

Anyway, this is all very nice and useful, but I was wondering when I graduate and lose my affiliation with my school, my certificate will also no longer be valid. Will there be a grace period after this happens in which I can still recover the files that I stored on my university dropbox, or will all my files simply vanish into thin air the moment that my school certificate stops working?

Comment: Entirely up to the school. Contact tech services and they'll tell you.